# Create a calendar with precreated events

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to create a calendar view which will have pre-created events(to come from the DB). Also I would be able to create events on each date with event duration. Is there any library(paid or free) or open source project to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create simple DayView calendar [github](https://github.com/srikanthgr/Calendar-DayView) and for Monthview Implementation u can check out this [Link](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/) you can modify this to display the events from the DB() make db calls in the below method create a hashmap and get the corresponding value in getView() method in gridcell adapter

```
private HashMap findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year, int month)
                    {
                        HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        // DateFormat dateFormatter2 = new DateFormat();
                        //                      
                        // String day = dateFormatter2.format("dd", dateCreated).toString();
                        //
                        // if (map.containsKey(day))
                        // {
                        // Integer val = (Integer) map.get(day) + 1;
                        // map.put(day, val);
                        // }
                        // else
                        // {
                        // map.put(day, 1);
                        // }
                        return map;
                    }
```

Comment: The github app is crashing in `DataInterface.java` at line no. 68, giving nullpointerException

Comment: i just tried Jack its working fine in that implementation i'm getting values from default calendar and it works for half n hour or 1 hr interval eg-9.00-9.30 or 10.00-12.00. so u can modify that Datainterface to read from database.

Comment: how are you trying to populate ?? if from database u need to change in datainterface.

Comment: I am not populating anything, just i imported the project into eclipse. Now how can I make it work?

Comment: trying adding some events in native calendar....if u face the same problem change DataInterface.java i just tried its workin fine :)